# grpc with mustEmbedUnimplemented*** method

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

Recently, grpc-go introduced the mustEmbedUnimplemented*** method.
It is used for forward compatibility.

In simple terms, I am unable to understand how it is helping and how earlier without it what problems we were facing?
In my structs now I use to add the following statement but, I don't know why...

```
type server struct {
     pdfpb.UnimplementedGreetServiceServer
}
```

In Github issue - https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3669 they debated over it, can someone please explain in simple terms how it is helping and how earlier without it what problems we were facing?

Answer (score 22):

This error comes newer versions of the `protoc-gen-grpc-go` compiler. Server implementations must now be forward-compatible.

Before this change, whenever you registered a server implementation, you would do something like this:

```
        pb.RegisterFooBarServiceServer(
            server,
            &FooBarServer{}, // or whatever you use to construct the server impl
        )
```

Which would result in a **compile-time** error in case your server has some missing method implementations.

With the newer proto compiler version, **forward-compatibility becomes opt-out**, which means two things:

1. you must now embed `UnimplementedFooBarServiceServer`, as the error message suggests. As I said, **this will not produce compiler errors** when you do not explicitly implement new methods (this is what forward compatibility means). Though it will result in a run-time error with `codes.Unimplemented` if you attempt to call an RPC that you didn't (or forgot) to explicitly implement.
2. **you can still opt-out** of forward compatibility by embedding instead `UnsafeFooBarServiceServer` (with `Unsafe` prefix). This interface simply declares the `mustEmbedUnimplementedFooBarServiceServer()` method which makes the error in the question go away, without forgoing a compiler errors in case you didn't explicitly implement the new handlers.

So for example:

```
// Implements the grpc FooBarServiceServer
type FooBarService struct {
    grpc.UnsafeFooBarServiceServer // consciously opt-out of forward compatibility
    // other fields
}
```

---

You can also generate code without forward compatibility by setting an option on `protoc-gen-grpc-go` plugin ([source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/v1.45.0/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc#future-proofing-services)):

```
protoc --go-grpc_out=require_unimplemented_servers=false:.
```

Note the `:.` after the `--go-grpc_out` option is used to set the path element.

Answer (score 8):

That was quite basic.

`UnimplementedGreetServiceServer` is a struct with all implemented methods.

When I add `pdfpb.UnimplementedGreetServiceServer` I am able to call `UnimplementedGreetServiceServer` defined methods.

That's how, if I add more RPC services in the proto file, then I don't need to add all RPC methods leading to forward compatibility.

Demo code is available at: https://github.com/parthw/fun-coding/tree/main/golang/understanding-grpc-change

Comment: So what is this actually helping? I'm definitely of the opinion that this isn't a feature and can cause breaking APIs. Why would I want to allow the generation of proto files into go files and not have them be implemented?

Comment: @swade I agree with you. I don't want RPCs failing with `Unimplemented` in case someone forgets to implement a handler. However there is a benefit in this change, which is that now you must make a conscious choice about whether to have forward compatibility or not. On the other side, you may not want failing builds whenever you upgrade the proto schema but not the grpc implementation. So they let you choose. Anyway you can still opt-out of fwd compat. See my answer for details

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that still have problems with `mustEmbededUnimplementedServiceServer` as suggested on the [Github Issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3794). the best solution is just to update your ServerStruct.

Ex.

```golang
type AuthenticationServiceServer struct {
}
```

To.

```golang
type AuthenticationServiceServer struct {
    service.UnimplementedAuthenticationServiceServer
}
```

that will solve the exception throw by Go when doing this.

```golang
grpcService.RegisterAuthenticationServiceServer(grpcServer, controller.AuthenticationServiceServer{})
```

Comment: Example code here https://github.com/alexcpn/go_grpc_2022